# jquery.datepicker auto check weekday checkbox

Tags: jquery

EDITED : I use this code to autocomplete the field weekday from the .datepicker

```
$(function() {
 $( "#dateeffective" ).datepicker({
  dayNames: [ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" ],
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
  altField: "#weekday",
  altFormat: "DD"     
 });
});
```

When I select a date, it shows in the field weekday, the number of the weekday (0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday...)
But what I need, instead of fill a text field, it should auto check the respective day from the following checkboxes (EDIT checkboxes id's now have [0,1,2...] (I don't mind to keep the weekday field if necessary)

```
  <input required="required" type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" id="eventweekday0" value="0">Sun
  <input required="required" type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" id="eventweekday1" value="1">Mon
  <input required="required" type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" id="eventweekday2" value="2">Tue
  <input required="required" type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" id="eventweekday3" value="3">Wed
  <input required="required" type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" id="eventweekday4" value="4">Thu
  <input required="required" type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" id="eventweekday5" value="5">Fri
  <input required="required" type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" id="eventweekday6" value="6">Sat
```

I need to tell javascript: if weekday field value change to 0, check Sunday, if changes to 1, check Monday...

I did try:

```
$(document).ready(function returndaynumber(){
  var daynumber = document.getElementById("weekday");
  document.getElementById("eventweekday" +daynumber).checked = true;
});
```

But no luck. I don't know how to modify my code to get this result.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the logic here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/78ajyyzj/

```
// work out selected date 
            var dateSelect = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); //used below

            var dayOfWeek = $.datepicker.formatDate('DD', dateSelect); //shows Monday
            $('#datepicker-day-of-week').text(dayOfWeek);
```

And then you can grab a option using id of the select item and check/uncheck.

```
$('.myCheckbox')[index_of_selected_day].checked = true;
```

**UPDATE**

Created an example jsfiddle of what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/mvLx59hb/22/

Comment: Sorry Tushar, but I'm new to javascript. I did edit my question what I did try so far... Hope you can help me. THanks!

Comment: Updated my answer with an example jsfiffle. Also added comments there, to understand how that processing work.